# Cannot Resolve method calling from other class in android?

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

I am having an activity

```
public class SettingActivity extends Activity {

    // here i am having my function
    // Boolean
    public static boolean ReadBoolean(Context context, final String key,
                                      final boolean defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return settings.getBoolean(key, defaultValue);
   }
}
```

But in my another class

```
public class MyServices extends Service
{
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Noti_flag= SettingActivity.ReadBoolean(context, "NotiOnOff", true);
        super.onCreate();
    }

}
```

[image: ReadBoolean is showing cannot resolve method]
    help me to solve this please thank you.

Comment: Both the below answers are right, use `SingleActivity.ReadBoolean(context, "NotiOnOff", true);`

Comment: anyway i have changed it into setting Activity, but also ReadBoolean is showing is in red color and showing cant resolve method

Comment: can you please add your new code here?

Comment: I have edited the above

Comment: public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        Log.d("Autostart", "BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast received. Executing starter service.");
        boolean isAutoStartEnabled = SettingActivity.ReadBoolean(context, "isAutoStartEnabled", true);  this is where i am getting my context

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean:

```
SingleActivity.ReadBoolean(...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using SettingActivity instead of SingleActivity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have made a typo instead of `SingleActivity` you are trying to use `SettingActivity`. You might try instead:

```
Noti_flag = SingleActivity.ReadBoolean(context, "NotiOnOff",true);
```

by the way if you follow javabean naming convention you might prefer to use:

```
readBoolean instead of `ReadBoolean`
```

**EDIT****
If Noti_flag is local variable you need to define its type as well:

```
boolean Noti_flag = SingleActivity.ReadBoolean(context, "NotiOnOff",true);
```

Comment: yes i have tried with the naming convention like readBoolean also but its not use.

Comment: First repleace SettingActivity to SingleActivity, then try again

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to call method from your service class .

```
   public class MyServices extends Service
    {
        public void onCreate()
        {
            Noti_flag= SettingActivity.ReadBoolean(getApplicationContext(), "NotiOnOff", true);
            super.onCreate();
        }
    }
```

you need to pass `getApplicationContext()` intends of context.